# Cant run JUnit test due classpath issue

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I have just downloaded a new project, which contains some tests.
I am having some problems running them, eclipse tells me that the class I am trying to run as test is not in the classpath 'well the icon says that(empty J icon)':

[image: eclipse's empty J icon]

Eclipse shows the 'run a Junit test' option, but won't run it, and shows in the run configs:
 `Can not find test class 'StatusQuerier' in project 'project-name'`

I think there is something wrong with the classpath's confguration, as eclipse suggests.
I have other classes in a different package of the same project that are in the classpath "full 'J' icon"
I have opened the "configure build path" panel but I can't find a helpful option.
Is the first time i run into this, I don't understand why, after downloading a project, some classes were added into classpath, and others don't...

Comment: Can you run another test class from that package? Is it a maven project? Maybe you try to run the test class from the parent module path and not from within the module itself? How does the directory structure look like? Can you run the test from the command line `mvn -Dtest=StatusQuerier test`?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with: Right click on package where the classis located > set as source folder.